# remove break tags from string using regex

Tags: sql, regex

This works great removing ALL html from a string/DB text type field, how can I omit break tags:

```
update hazHRA set identityRisk=dbo.RegexReplace('<(?:[^>''"]*|([''"]).*?\1)*>',
'',identityRisk,1,1);
```

I wish to keep the

```
<br>
```

only

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

`(?i)<(?:(?!br>|br/>)[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>`

**(?i)**: Case insensitive.

**(?!br>|br/>)**: Negative lookahead.

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dW5hP9).

---

If you could use quantifiers in lookaheads you may use this:

`(?i)<(?:(?!br\s*>|br\s*/>)[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>`

This will ensure to not match `<br   >` with spaces.

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yT1sG4).

Comment: I would also suggest adding in case insensitivity to handle any weird combination of `BR` you can find.  Also add in wildcards between the `br` and the brackets to handle any number of spaces users could add in the HTML tag, see [here](http://rubular.com/r/ywhcBEfFdn).

Comment: @Walls I tested it using PHP PCRE preg_replace function, the problem is that it can't use lookahead with quantifiers. I couldn't find an online SQL regex tester, so I'm not sure if it will work for SQL ?

Comment: I see your point about the question leaning towards SQL, where I normally just test regex type stuff in a normal online regex tester like Rubular.  If the quantifiers can't be used that makes sense, but I think the case insensitivity would make the regex stronger for the OP.

Comment: I am a bit confused when I run you one where I have been testing here http://regexpal.com/  I can see a red block and it does not work for me.  I am pasting this one in there (?i)<(?:(?!br>|br/>)[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>

Comment: @Mat41 `(?:i)` is to enable case insensitive matching, so in regexpal you have to remove that part and check "Case insensitive (i)" in the menu bar.

Comment: Agh I see.  As you can tell i am regex dumb. So when I run it in my SQL statement I should include all of you charcters inside my single quotes EG '(?i)<(?:(?!br>|br/>)[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>'

Comment: @Mat41 As I mentioned before, I couldn't find a SQL Regex tester, the code above works in "general" and I tested it with PHP. So the only way to know if it works is to try it :)

Comment: @HamZa unfortunatley it give me procedure of function has to many arguments when I use it like this SELECT  dbo.RegexReplace('(?i)<(?:(?!br>|br/>)[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>',
   '',context,1,1) from hazHRA